# Import mp3 files through FileChooser to clickable Labels

Tags: file, javafx, mp3

I want to import mp3 files as clickable labels, but i have no idea how to handle it. I am doing graphical user interface through JavaFX. Image below will explain more.

[image: mmpc]

Answer (score 0):

You can get all Files from a directory by doing something like this:

```
File myfolder = new File("path/to/directory");
File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  if (allFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + allFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + allFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```

But instead of printing it to the output you can add Labels with the file.

Maybe something like this is what you want:

```
File myfolder = new File("your/path");
File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles();
VBox yourBox = new VBox();

for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  if (allFiles[i].isFile()) {
    yourBox.getChildren().add(new Label(allFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    //Do whatever you want to do with subfolders.
  }
}
```

Edit: for selecting a folder at runtime you can use:

DirectoryChooser 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html
Or a FileChooser, which allows selecting multiple Files.

Edit full code (tested):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("File Chooser");

        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        final Button openMultipleButton = new Button("Open Files...");

        VBox yourBox = new VBox();

        openMultipleButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                List<File> list = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
                if (list != null) {
                    for (File file : list) {

                        yourBox.getChildren().add(new Label(file.getName()));

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        HBox all = new HBox();
        all.getChildren().addAll(openMultipleButton, yourBox);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(12);
        rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(all);
        rootGroup.setPrefSize(400, 400);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootGroup));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    }
```

Hope this helped,
Steffi

Comment: But I want import files from filechooser from that window, this code is for static choose of folder... I need to choose what I want to import.

Comment: So you can use a DirectoryChooser for selecting the Folder. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html 
Or use a FileChooser and select multiple Files.

Comment: @FXML
    private void load(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        
       
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
 if (file != null) {
                        openFile(file);
                    }
File[] allFiles = file.listFiles();
HBox box = new HBox();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 
    box.getChildren().add(new Label(allFiles[i].getName()));
  
}     
    }

Comment: thanks so much, but I want FileInputStream of that Labels, not just print names of files.